# Finding long file names?

Tags: windows-xp, unzip, 7zip

I have some zipped plug-ins, when I try to unpack that the unpacking fails. When I looked deep into it I found that the some of the files are exceeding 256 characters, which I guess is not allowed in `WINDOWS` operating system.

So my question is there any way to find out if any file name inside a particular folder exceeds 256 characters?

I'm using `WINDOWS XP` operating system.

Thanks in advance!!

Anand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without having your zip file is a bit harder to find out if the problem is exactly what you said... AFAI remember, 7zip would truncate the long file names, not "not extract" them. But I don't have any zip with long names to test.

I'd try some things:

1. Open the zip file with 7zip and try to rename the long names, instead of extracting them.
2. Try to open the zip file with other zip app, like (izarc)[http://www.izarc.org/news.html], and rename the files
3. If you don't have access to another computer, try to use one of the available online unzippers. For example: http://jcarleemae.wen.ru/extract.html